# Why UICollectionView ReloadItems always calls CellForItemAt twice for each item?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

Why UICollectionView ReloadItems always calls CellForItemAt twice for each item? And how to prevent duplicate calls? How to prevent spending double resources for reloading of selected cells? ReloadData() calls CellForItemAt only once. But it's a waste of resources either to reload all rows and sections when only 2-3 items needed to be updated.

The code example may anything with UICollectiionView. For example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func onTestButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("test button tapped")
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)])
    }

    let reuseIdentifier = "my cell" 
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        print("cell for item at \(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

When tapping "test button", console output will be:

```
test button tapped
cell for item at 2
cell for item at 2
```

But I need to reload "item at 2" only once, and I don't want to reload all items using reloadData().

Answer (score 0):

You should not make any assumptions about how often the system will call your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method. Just build and return cells when it asks you to. If it sometimes asks you for the same cell twice, just give it the same cell twice.

Collection views and table views ask your to return cells frequently, as the user scrolls. Your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method (or the equivalent table view method) needs to be fast. It shouldn't do network requests, or even decompress JPEG or compressed PNG images from disk unless you cache the results.

Comment: On the one hand I understood your point. On the other hand, I understand when cell reload is needed for objective reasons (scrolling etc.). But I can't accept that each cell is being reloaded twice when objectively needed to reload only once.

I have 1000 cells. Each one reloads video from data source every time cellForItemAt is being called. It's a huge waste of resources when doing twice the same.
It makes me either to create some routing skipping 1st call of cellForItemAt initiated by reloadItems, or to refuse reloadItems at all and update cells manually.
What do you think?

Comment: Worse, `reloadItems(at:)` calls `prepareForReuse` on cells, even if it's not actually a cell that was in the reload call. Huge waste of resources, indeed.

Comment: If you are recreating your model data every time your data source gets asked for a cell, you are doing it wrong. Your `cellForRow(at:)` method needs to be as fast as it possibly can. If the user is scrolling rapidly through a table view/collection view, that method is going to be hit **hard**. You need to have a model object that is pre-loaded with the data for the cells on-screen and large numbers of neighboring cells (or EVERY cell, if memory allows.)

Comment: If you don’t allow for caching data and the user scrolling back and forth, your app’s performance is going to be bad. If you write your data source correctly, the fact that the system decides to ask for the same cell more than once won’t matter.